# Use Common Table Expression to get difference between two sets of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to use a common table expression to find the differences between two queries I wrote. The first query returns how many patients belong to each ROOMID(each ID represent a specific room).

Second query I have is how many patients that belong to each ROOMId have surgery operated on them. PatientID represent each patient.

```
select roomID, count(distinct patientID) as totalinsurgery
from data with (nolock)    
where ptprocess = 'surgery'    
group by clientid, batchid
```

Second query:

```
select CAroomid, sum(patientsinroom) as patientsinroom
from data   
group by caroomid
```

So the idea behind is try to get the 'difference' in result of the two query. So how many patients in the room went to surgery. What is the best way to use common table expression to get the result?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  In addition, your first query is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry I'm confused, you mean sql server?

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). Every sql question you've posted includes it!

Comment: And please show some sample data (as DDL+DML) and expected results (as tabular text).

Answer (score 0):

> So how many patients in the room went to surgery.

I suspect you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select roomId,
       count(distinct case when ptprocess = 'surgery' then patientID end) as num_surgery
       count(distinct patientID) as total
from data
group by roomId;
```

Note:  I have no idea why you are using `count(distinct)`.  Can a patient really occur more than one time in a room?

Comment: I suspect "room" is used in the sense of "consulting room" where a patient may visit more than once over time.